# php no muestra mensajes echo

Tags: javascript, php, html

buenas. tengo un problema.
tengo 3 archivos: es un formulario.
uno es un html con datos a llenar y lo manda a un javascript (que es el otro archivo) para que los datos se ejecuten en mysql por php.
todo bien hasta ahi (porque el codigo me funciona). el caso es que en el codigo php tengo algo como esto.

esto tengo en htmll

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="matriculaNueva">ciudad</label>
      <input  type="text" id="ciudad" value=""  class="form-control" />
    </div>
       
  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="matriculaNueva">sistema</label>
      <input  type="text" id="sistema" value=""  class="form-control" />
    </div>

    
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button id="cancelarDos" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    <button id="agregarDos" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addSystem()" >Guardar</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="idOculto">
  </div>
```

esto en javascript

```
function addSystem() {
var id = $("#sistema").val();
var ciudad = $("#ciudad").val();


    $.post("ajax/sistema.php", {
        id: id,
        ciudad: ciudad
        },
        function (data, status) {
           
            
        }
    );
```

}

y esto en php

```
$sistema=$_POST['id'];
    $ciudad=$_POST['ciudad'];
    
            $sql = "select  (count(*)) as total from sistemasyCiudades where ciudad = '$ciudad' and sistema = '$sistema'";
                $proceso=mysqli_query($con,$sql);   
                $rows=$proceso->fetch_assoc();
                $num_res=$proceso->num_rows;
                $total=$rows["total"];

    if (empty($total)) {

                    $query = "INSERT INTO sistemasyCiudades(sistema,ciudad)
                 VALUES('$sistema', '$ciudad')";
                if (!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
                    exit(mysqli_error($con));

                }
                
    }else{
        echo "no se agrego";
            echo "<script>
                                
                                alert('datos existentes');
                                
                                
                                </script>";
    }
```

cuando lleno los datos en el formulario, con datos exitentes (a proposito, para ver si muestra el alert) no pasa absolutamente nada.
en php todo funciona: si el resultado de la consulta esta vacio, agrega los datos y si no, no agrega nada. pero tambien deberia mostrar el alert y no lo hace

Comment: echo "<script> alert("mensaje"); </script>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al ejecutar `$.post` estás haciendo una llamada ajax, y el contenido de la respuesta (si el status es 200) está dentro de tu callback en la variable que defines como `data`.

Esta variable contiene un `string` con todo el texto que se ha impreso por medio de php y no es anexado al documento actual, por lo que tienes que parsearlo o anexarlo por tu cuenta, por ejemplo:

```
function addSystem() {
var id = $("#sistema").val();
var ciudad = $("#ciudad").val();


    $.post("ajax/sistema.php", {
        id: id,
        ciudad: ciudad
        },
        function (data, status) {
           
            $('body').append( data );
            
        }
    );
```

Esto también puedes verificarlo en la pestaña "network" de tus herramientas de desarrollo de chrome o firefox.

Comment: gracias, me sirivio de maravilla